# Please remove [Masked] before it gets out of hand

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across this tag in a review [masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masked).

It currently has <strike>14</strike> 58 questions tagged.

- It has no summary,
- no wiki and
- no synonyms.
- 0 followers
- It is a badly defined tag, and
- adds no distinctive value
- It will not make questions more discoverable.

**Please burn it with fire, before it spreads.**

Comment: Actually there are [58 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masked?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Comment: Seems like it's split between numpy-mask questions and "other questions that also have the word mask in them", about 50/50

Comment: (Unmasks a user) "User 123456789?!" "Yes, I created that tag, and I would have gotten the Taxonomist badge if it weren't for you meddling meta users!"

Comment: A lot of them seemed to also be tagged with [tag:numpy]. Maybe [tag:numpy-masked] should be a thing?

Comment: yea this tag sucks. good catch

Comment: @dav_i I don't see a need for adding a new tag at all. Just use [tag:numpy]

Comment: Just came across [tag:bitmask]. It seems, in hindsight, a good fit for a lot of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the fire, but the tag is no longer in use on any question, and will soon vanish from the list of known tags.

Sorry about the taxonomist badge — maybe you should add the [numpy-masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy-masked) tag instead?